# Makefile with multiple main functions

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors

```
all: program1 program2

program1: StringListDemo.o
    gcc -Wall -std=c11 -Iinclude src/StringListDemo.c src/LinkedListAPI.c -o program1

program2: StructListDemo.o
    gcc -Wall -std=c11 -Iinclude src/StructListDemo.c src/LinkedListAPI.c -o program2
```

Trying to compile folder with two files with main functions but keep getting error.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `StringListDemo.o', needed by `program1'.  Stop.
```

Comment: If you compile commands takes a `.c` file why do you depend on `.o` ?

Comment: From your title, you only have the problem when you add multiple program targets into your makefile. Are you sure that it works with 1 program?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention `StringListDemo.o`, but give no rule for it, `make` looks for an [*implicit rule*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit) that tells how to update it. In other words, `make` looks for `StringListDemo.c` file which apparently does not exist in the current directory. However, you also mention `src/StringListDemo.c`, and the `program1` target apparently depends on it. So you should change `StringListDemo.o` in the prerequisite list to `src/StringListDemo.o`:

```
program1: src/StringListDemo.o
```

The same logic applies to `program2`.

---

If `src/StringListDemo.c` is supposed to be compiled with special options (different from defaults), then add the `StringListDemo.o` target explicitly, e.g.:

```
StringListDemo.o: src/StringListDemo.c
    gcc ...
```